# How can I alter the style of one type of reference if I'm happy with all the others?

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing using the RSC style for referencing,, but I've been asked to provide more information for technical reports so they're easier for a reader to find. For most of them I do have more information, but I don't know how to ask LaTeX to display it.

(This is the first time I've asked a question and posted an MWE so please edit to improve it.)

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=chem-rsc,
            sorting=none
]{biblatex}

\let\cite=\supercite

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{Leipold67,
 author =       "M. H. Leipold and H. T. Smith",
  title =        "A study of the structure of grain boundaries in polycrystalline magnesium oxide",
  number =      "NASA CR-83111",
  series =      "NASA Contractor Report",
  publisher =      "NASA",
  year =         "1967",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}

Foo bar baz.\cite{Leipold67}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}


\end{document}
```

This one isn't actually too bad, because it has a distinctive title, but it shows what information is shown/not shown in my bibliography. The ones with titles like "Fuel Sources" are more of a problem in terms of a reader finding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the presentation of an entry type is controlled by its bibliography driver. In case of `chem-rsc` you can find some drivers in [`chem-rsc.bbx`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/blob/main/chem-rsc.bbx) while the remaining drivers are inherited from the `biblatex` core (in [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)).

As you mention yourself, your example entry gives the fairly reasonable (or at least 'findable')

[image: M. H. Leipold and H. T. Smith, A study of the structure of grain boundaries in polycrystalline magnesium oxide, tech. rep. NASA CR-83111, 1967.]

If you keep in mind which fields `@report` knows (it has an `institution` and not a `publisher`, what you put in `series` is generally handled by `type`+`number`; all details can be found in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)) you can get slightly more verbose, but all the mentions of "NASA" seem a bit redundant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=chem-rsc,
  sorting=none
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{Leipold67,
  author      = {M. H. Leipold and H. T. Smith},
  title       = {A Study of the Structure of Grain Boundaries
                 in Polycrystalline Magnesium Oxide},
  number      = {NASA CR-83111},
  type        = {NASA Contractor Report},
  institution = {NASA},
  year        = {1967},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo bar baz.\autocite{Leipold67}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: M. H. Leipold and H. T. Smith, A Study of the Structure of Grain Boundaries in Polycrystalline Magnesium Oxide, NASA Contractor Report NASA CR-83111, NASA, 1967.]

Note that according to the PDF available via https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/196700121160 the authors are actually Smyth & Leipold, not Leipold & Smith (though the metadata say Smith - could also be a typo in the PDF ...).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=chem-rsc,
  sorting=none
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{Leipold67,
  author      = {H. T. Smyth and M. H. Leipold},
  title       = {A Study of the Structure of Grain Boundaries
                 in Polycrystalline Magnesium Oxide},
  number      = {32-1042},
  type        = {Technical report},
  institution = {Jet Propulsion Laboratory},
  year        = {1967},
  url         = {https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/196700121160},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo bar baz.\autocite{Leipold67}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: H. T. Smyth and M. H. Leipold, A Study of the Structure of Grain Boundaries in Polycrystalline Magnesium Oxide, Technical report 32-1042, Jet Propulsion Laboratory, 1967.]